# android webview postUrl change user-agent

Tags: android, post, webview, head

all
I want to POST url in webview with custom user-agent,how can i do it?

I know

```
webView.loadUrl(url,extraHeaders);
```

can with the custom head data,but the request is GET

and,

```
webView.postUrl(v, EncodingUtils.getBytes(data, "base64"));
```

can POST the data,but it can't change the head data...

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can't. You could do the post manually, then use `loadDataWithBaseUrl` on the WebView from the response.

Answer (score 1):

Before using postUrl have your tried something along the lines of:

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setUserAgentString("<Add User Agent Here>");

mWebView.postUrl(.....);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. postUrl seems to override all WebSettings